# C# override function how to return null

Tags: java, c#, inheritance

So I am trying to implement some inheritance and I am running into an issue. I am coming from java so I am basically trying to convert code. So for example in java you might have this.

```
public class galaxyFactory extends abstractFactory
{
    @Override
    public galaxy setType()
    {   
        return new Spiral();
    }

    @Override
    SolarSystem setType() 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will return a new Spiral object if your after a galaxy, and overrides the SolarSystem setType with a simple return null. However when trying to convert this into c# i come up with something like this. Which DOES NOT work, it errors out with "NullReferenceException was unhandled"

```
  class GalaxyFactory: AbstractFactory
  {
    public override Galaxy CreateProductA()
    {
        return new spiral();
    }
    public override SolarSystem CreateProductB()
    {
        return null;
    }
  }
```

What would I have to change my return null to get the same effect in c#?

Comment: If you return null from a method, then try to access a property on the value returned you'll get a null reference.  Are you receiving the error in the code shown or later in the app?

Comment: Not an error but a error after the app starts running. It is happening when I am trying to create galaxy,  which should be returning spiral(); but is instead calling this null method.

Comment: It sounds as though you have not provided the whole picture here.  What is calling the null method? Which method are you calling? And what are you doing with the results of the call?

Comment: Could you please add certain code part where the exception raises?

Answer (score 1):

This error occures because you trying working with uninitialized object. When you get SolarSystem by using CreateProductB, actually you get null object, and then when you try work with this object obviously it will throw NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

```
class GalaxyFactory: AbstractFactory
  {
    public override Galaxy CreateProductA()
    {
        return spiral();
    }
    public override SolarSystem CreateProductB()
    {
        return null;
    }
  }
```

null is not a function.. So dont write null followed by (); It's just null;

Comment: Sorry this was a typo, the question has been edited to reflect the code. return null; is what is causing the error.